# c# Linq query to find the object in a list that is missing an annotation

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list that contains 2 objects.

```
object 1 = { Annotations : ["Ann1", "Ann2", "Ann3"] }

object 2 = { Annotations : ["Ann1", "Ann2"] }
```

I need to be able to grab **object 1** based on which annotations it has and not the `count` of annotations.

currently I have tried 2 approaches with little luck.

```
var object = objects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Annotations.Any(x => x == "Ann1")
                                       && x.Annotations.Any(x => x == "Ann2")
                                       && x.Annotations.Any(x => x != "Ann3"));
```

My second approach was similar to the first but I split up the first 2 checks from the 3rd

Neither of these worked as the third check always failed.

How do I grab object 2 based on the fact that the third annotation is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below LINQ expression finds the only (if any) element without annotation `"Ann3"`. If multiple elements are missing `"Ann3"` the query will throw an exception.

```
var myObjects = new[]
        {
            new { Annotations = new[] {"Ann1", "Ann2", "Ann3"}},
            new { Annotations = new[] {"Ann1", "Ann2"}}
        };

var objectWithoutAnn3 = myObjects.SingleOrDefault(o => !o.Annotations.Contains("Ann3"));
```

Your own approach is quite close, but the `.Any` is behaving a bit differently than what you expect. To break down your query:

```
var object = objects
    .SingleOrDefault(x => 
        x.Annotations.Any(x => x == "Ann1") // At least 1 annotation is Ann1.
     && x.Annotations.Any(x => x == "Ann2") // At least 1 annotation is Ann2.
     && x.Annotations.Any(x => x != "Ann3")); // At least 1 annotation is not Ann3.
```

Since two of your three elements *are not Ann3*, your third comparison will be true, if annotation contains anything that is not Ann3.

If you want to continue with your approach, you have to modify the third comparison to use `.all` instead of `.any`.

```
var object = objects
    .SingleOrDefault(x => 
        x.Annotations.Any(x => x == "Ann1") // At least 1 annotation is Ann1.
     && x.Annotations.Any(x => x == "Ann2") // At least 1 annotation is Ann2.
     && x.Annotations.All(x => x != "Ann3")); // None of the annotations are Ann3.
```